# Javascript Hover Cursor Pointer

Tags: jquery, css, hover

Trying to use Jquery to do a Cursor Pointer on hover:

```
$('#example td').hover(function() {
$(this).css('cursor','pointer');
});
```

I do not want to put it in CSS, I want it in Jquery.

What do I need to do to fix this?

http://jsfiddle.net/Egttj/

Comment: Why don't you want to use CSS?

Comment: jQuery isn't a replacement for CSS.

Comment: "How can I bang in a nail using a glass bottle?"

Comment: @DJ Howarth: I don't know what mistake did you get while running your code. I have executed it perfectly in the jsFiddle. May be I guess you probably have forgotten to turn on the jQuery in the jsFiddle while executing it.

Comment: It seems to work here after I cleared up your jquery, you forgot to close the first click function and the searchform and button aren't declared in your html (i changed it to #example tr)

Comment: @Blender [It's really great and does all things](http://www.doxdesk.com/img/updates/20091116-so-large.gif)

Comment: **0_o** if you add the `cursor:pointer` to the css, the only time you'd ever notice it, is when you hover.... so this is inherently a strange request (http://jsfiddle.net/Egttj/25/)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It seems to work here after I cleared up your jquery, you forgot to close the first click function and the searchform and button aren't declared in your html (i changed it to #example tr)

Basically your jQuery wasn't that well coded (there also was a line with 5.}) on it that didn't belong there).

I also set the "your framework" to *jQuery* instead of the standard selected *mooTools*

This is the complete jQuery code I got after i deleted some unnecessary code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#example tr').click(function() {
        var href = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
        if(href) {
            window.location = href;
        }
    });

    $('#example tr').hover(function() {
        $(this).css('cursor','pointer');
    });

});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Egttj/18/)

Answer (score 9):

I couldn't comment Tobias Nilsons's answer for some reason, so here it is as an answer.

```
$('#example td').css('cursor', 'pointer');`
```

There's no reason why'd you want specify the style as applied on hover anyway. The cursor really only appears on hover, so.

The fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Egttj/15/

I'm assuming simply specifying the corresponding rule in a stylesheet causes a little trouble for you. But, yes, as everyone pointed out, it would really be the best and simplest way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Comparing the first method

```
$('#example tr').hover(function() {
    $(this).css('cursor','pointer');
});
```

With the second method

```
$('#example td').css('cursor', 'pointer');`
```

I would recommend to stick to the first since it can be extended to whatever jQuery we want like:

```
$('#example tr').hover(function() {

    $(this).css('cursor','pointer');

    $(this).click(function() {
       var href = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
       if(href) {
          window.location = href;
       }
    });

});
```